# How do I get 1 column with 10 varchars in it into 10 columns of 1 var char each?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am very new to SQL.  I have a few CSV files of books that were sent to me by some webmasters and I am trying to sort them out into a database table.
  My input(CSV file) looks like this=

```
Book Title | Volume | price | Genre |
Book | 1 | 10.99 | Science Fiction, Fantasy, Midevial, Magic|
```

Some of the titles have as many as 10 genres.  My key question, is how do I take the info under the genres column and split it into different columns so that each column only has one genre?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.  What you want to do is create a `BookGenres` table, with columns for `book_id` and `genre`.

You can load your existing CSV data into a staging table, with a column for the `genres`.

Then you can do something like this:

```
insert into bookgenres (book_id, genre)
    select book, substring_index(genres, ', ', 1)
    from staging;

insert into bookgenres (book_id, genre)
    select book, substring_index(substring_index(genres, ', ', 2), ', ', -1)
    from staging
    where genres like '%, %';

insert into bookgenres (book_id, genre)
    select book, substring_index(substring_index(genres, ', ', 3), ', ', -1)
    from staging
    where genres like '%, %, %'

. . .

insert into bookgenres (book_id, genre)
    select book, substring_index(substring_index(genres, ', ', 10), ', ', -1)
    from staging
    where genres like '%, %, %, %, %, %, %, %, %, %';
```

There are some tricks for shortening this, but for a one-time data load it is simple enough to just write the SQL that you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What if this was a weekly data load? What would be the difference?

Comment: @Database . . . Once you write the code it will just work.  If this is a regular load, you might want to consider other formats but that could be additional work.

Comment: When I try to compile the code, I get a syntax error on each of the where statements.  The error reads "Syntax error: 'where' (where) is not valid input at this position. "

Comment: @Database . . . `where` should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I found my mistake like 3 minutes ago lol.  But it is telling me the 3rd insert is the syntax error now